# I want to return address of local variable

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, warnings

I have a method that stores global pointers in a data structure and at some point tries to get them out of the data structure and return them.I want to be able to return them because I know they are ok but the compiler does not allow me.It thinks they are only local because they have just been taken from the data structure ,but in reality I have taken them from outside.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No; the compiler knows better than you.  You can't safely return the address of a local variable that is not also `static`.  You can return the address of a global variable as a pointer from a function, but that isn't what you seem to be trying to  do.  And if you do this, be aware of the consequences for threading (if the value in the variable changes, the consequences for threaded code are dire; if it is accessing a readonly — immutable, unchanging — value, it is not a problem).

Listen to your compiler; it is trying to protect you from yourself.  It knows more about C++ than you do.

To persuade us that the compiler is wrong, you'll have to show your code — but it is very unlikely that what you show will be valid.

Comment: Thank you!I 'll think about making the variable static.